# Traversing JSON data from Angular Factory

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular controller that uses a factory to return a response from a JSON file.
When I try to traverse the data returned I get the following error seen in the comment.
However if I use the realArticleData object inside of HTML within angular brackets it transverses perfectly. I believe it has something to do with the promise returned by the factory but I am not sure.

Controller Snippet:

```
function SpecialOrderItemsCtrl($scope, $location, articleDataService) {
    $scope.realArticleData = articleDataService.getArticles();
    //This throws TypeError: Cannot read property 'thdCustomer' of undefined
    $scope.custInfo = $scope.realArticleData.articles.thdCustomer;
}
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<div ng-controller=SpecialOrderItemsCtrl>
<label>Raw Article JSON</label>
<p>{{realArticleData}}</p>
<label>Json transversed by one level</label>
<p>{{realArticleData.articles}}</p>
<label>THD CUstomer </label>
<p>{{realArticleData.articles.thdCustomer}}</p>
</div>
```

Factory:

```
function articleDataService($rootScope, $http) {
    articleDataService.data = {};
    articleDataService.getArticles = function() {
    $http.get('articleData.json')
        .success(function(data) {
            articleDataService.data.articles = data;
        });
        return articleDataService.data;
    };
    return articleDataService;
}
sendDesign.factory('articleDataService', articleDataService);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are dealing with promises. Therefore, you need to deal with them asynchronously.
as in

```
angular.module('plunker', []).controller('SpecialOrderItemsCtrl', ['$scope', 'articleDataService',  function($scope, articleDataService){
  // when promise is resolved, set the scope variable
  articleDataService.getArticles().then(function(articles){
      // store any data from json that you want on the scope for later access in your templates
      $scope.articles = articles;
  })
}]).factory('articleDataService',['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){
  var data = null;
  return {
    getArticles: function() {
      var promise;
      if(data === null) {
        promise = $http.get('articleData.json').then(function(response){
          // cache the response
          data = response;
          return response;
        });
      } else {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // promise is immediately resolved with the cached data
        // this way both cached and async data can be handled consistently
        promise = deferred.promise;
      }
      return promise;
    }
  } ;
}]);
```

Plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/7Oas2T

Comment: The link to the plunker is http://plnkr.co/edit/7Oas2T and you had a syntax error in the controller by scope. I added the ] and now I get Error: Argument 'SpecialOrderItemsCtrl' is not a function, got string.

Comment: Syntax error was fixed, I now get Object #<Object> has no method 'getArticles'.

Comment: yep, found my problem, fixing it in plunkr before bringing it here

Comment: There was a typo in the name of $http service, as well as a disconnect between expected data in the scope and what controller was providing. Plunkr in my answer should work now

Answer (score 2):

Change your service to:

```
articleDataService.getArticles = function() {
    $http.get('articleData.json').then(function(result) {
        return result.data
    });
}
```

And in your controller:

```
articleDataService.getArticles().then(function(data) {
    $scope.realArticleData = data;
    $scope.custInfo = $scope.realArticleData.articles.thdCustomer;
});
```

You need to follow the promise pattern back to the controller, else you're not waiting for your call to finish and you'll be receiving `undefined`

Comment: I believe that caching the http response was one of the intents of the original code. With your approach, every call to getArticles will issue an http request(which may or may not be 304d)

Comment: Still having difficulty implementing your solution. Will accept once I figure it out.

Comment: Create a plunkr that demonstrates your issues. One thing that couldve cause problems is changes to the scope from within the promise in the controller. I updated the code to be wrapped in $scope.apply. See if that works

Answer (score 2):

The key point to remember is that promises do not return values, they *do something with a value* when or if a value arrives.

This answer is based on answers from @VladimirGurovich and @tymeJV.

Here's a simple factory:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);    

app.factory('Names', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    url: 'names.json',
    fetch: function() {
      return $http.get(this.url, {cache: true}).then(function(json) {
        return json.data;
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

The `Names` factory itself returns an object. The `fetch` method returns the promise chain from `$http.get`. This uses `.then()` instead of `.success()` so the result can be chained. The factory could return the `$http` promise directly, but giving the operation a name seems clearer to me.

@VladimirGurovich's answer handles caching manually, but Angular can do that for us, just send a config object like `{config: true}` to `$http.get` along with the url.

Here's a simple little controller which depends on data from the `Names` factory:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ["$scope", "Names", function($scope, Names) {
    Names.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.names = data.names;
    });
}]);
```

When the `Names.fetch()` promise completes, `$scope.names` is populated with the returned data.

Here's a Plunker based on this: http://plnkr.co/edit/nMx1XL